# Stream Write between two HTML Tags

Tags: html, vb.net, streamreader, streamwriter

If this example I am first iterating through a file directory to get all files that have not been renamed yet, I am doing this by identifying the ones with the current year on it (because it is produced with a time-stamp) Once that is complete it extracts those files to a temporary directory where from there i want to read the index page within the files and write it to a text file so i can then rename the previous extracted zip based on the information the index has. I hit a snag because i cannot come up with accurate enough logic to isolate the portion of the HTML i want to extract. What I do know is
1. The information is located between the second pair of  tags and the first three words after the tag is "Persons Record For" Any help isolating and writing just this tag would be greatly appreciated.

-Method i have tried already was to strip all html entirely but i found that to be inconsistent and cumbersome

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict Off

Imports System
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.IO.Compression
```

Module Modulel

```
Sub Main()

    Dim year As String
    year = Date.Today.Year
    Dim sc As New Shell32.Shell()
    'Dim EFMD As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\Pepper\Desktop\In")
    Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\Pepper\Desktop\In")
    For Each fi In di.GetFiles("*" + year + "*")
        'Dim startPath As String = "c:\example\start"
        Dim zipPath As String = "C:\Users\Pepper\Desktop\In\" + fi.ToString
        Dim extractPath As String = "C:\Users\Pepper\Desktop\Out\" + fi.ToString + "\"
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath)

        Console.WriteLine(fi)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()

    Dim di_t As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\Pepper\Desktop\Out")
    For Each fi In di_t.GetFiles("*" + year + "*")
        Dim g As String = "C:\Users\Pepper\Desktop\OUT\" + fi.ToString + "\INDEX.HTM"
        Dim h As String = "C:\Users\Pepper\Desktop\OUT\" + fi.ToString + "\INDEX" + fi.ToString + ".TXT"
        Dim sw As StreamWriter
        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(g)
        sw = New StreamWriter(h)
        Dim line As String
        Do
            line = sr.ReadLine
            sw.WriteLine(line)
        Loop Until line.Trim = 'need logic here
        sw.WriteLine(line)
        sr.Close()
    Next
End Sub
```

End Module
'Unzip the file confirming the person identification, once verified rename source file with name and person ID. 
'Go back and delete extracted files, put files in a temp folder
'Read/Write the file until we get the person name, so we can use that to rename

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-  instance" xmlns:voc="urn:hl7-org:v3/voc" xmlns:n2="urn:hl7-org:v3/meta/voc"       xmlns:n1="urn:hl7-org:v3">
<head>
<title>Person Identification Sheet</title>
<style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: black;
        }
        td
        {
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        h2
        {
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .dHeader
        {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        .dFooter
        {
            background-color: #e4e7f1;
        }
        .dSectionTitle
        {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        .dTable
        {
            border: 0px #ffffff solid;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .dTableHeading
        {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .dTableHeadingCell
        {
            padding-right: 20px;                
        }
        .dTableRow0
        {
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
        }
        .dTableRow1
        {
        }
        .dTableCell
        {
            padding-right: 20px;                
        }
        .pHeader
        {
            background-color: #2f3c6e;
        }
        .pHeaderLabel
        {
            font-weight: normal;
            color: white;
        }
        .pHeaderValue
        {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: white;
        }
        .pHeaderName
        {
            font-size: 22px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: white;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h2> Person record for  Jon D. Doe  ( PID:  2813308004 )  </h2>
<b>  Gender: </b>Male<b>  DOB: </b>June 10, 2011<br />
```

Comment: Could you show us a sample of the HTML?  Just the relevant portion and a little of the surrounding content, please.

Comment: sure should say its the second instance of h2 not the second tag

Comment: I only see one H2 element here.

Comment: the h2 portion of the inline styling